# How to send data via SPI between Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: python, c++, spi, wiringpi

I hope you can help.

I am currently using SPI to communicate between a Raspberry Pi (master) and Arduino (slave).

Currently, I have two codes, one for the master and the other the slave.

However, I am finding it difficult to transfer data across the two devices.

**The Raspberry Pi code - master**

```
import wiringpi
import iostream
import spidev
import time
import sys

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
SPI_CHANNEL = 0
SPI_CLOCK_SPEED = 1000000

def main():
    wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()
    fd = wiringpi.wiringPiSPISetup(SPI_CHANNEL, SPI_CLOCK_SPEED)

    if fd == -1:
        print("Failed to init SPI communication.")

    else:
        print("SPI communication successfully setup.")

        buff = [23, 0]
        wiringpi.wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, buff)
        print("Data returned: ", buff[1])
        main()
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The Arduino code - slave**

```
#include <SPI.h>
void setup() {
  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
  // turn on interrupts
  SPI.attachInterrupt();
}
// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  byte c = SPDR;
  SPDR = c+10;
}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) for SPI
void loop () { }
```

**What happens when run? ...**

Firstly I verify then upload the Arduino code, then run the raspberry pi script.

Within the Raspberry Pi terminal it prints: "SPI communication successfully setup".

From here two things can happen. Either the code just hangs, and does nothing or an error appears. The error states: Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.

**What should happen when run?...**

The code should send the number 23 from the Raspberry Pi. The Arduino should receive 23 and +10. This new number (33) should be sent to the Raspberry Pi and printed within the Raspberry Pi terminal.

**Other notes**

Raspberry Pi

- master
- Running Ubuntu
- Using Python3

Arduino

- Slave
- Using C++

**What do I need help with?**
If possible...

- Does anyone knows how to fix this code, to allow it to run correctly?
- Has anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Any help or advice would be great!

**EDIT

**How are they connected?**

I have the following connections Raspberry Pi on the left to the Arduino on the right.

- MOSI (GPIO 10) -----> MOSI (PIN11)
- MISO (GPIO 09) -----> MISO (PIN12)
- SCLK (GPIO 11) -----> SCLK (PIN 13)
- GROUND (PIN 25) --> GROUND

**What happens on the Arduino side?**

Currently nothing happens in the arduino terminal. I presume this is because the code gets stuck at buf = [23, 0] on the raspberry pi code. Meaning nothing has been sent to the arduino.

**Notes**

Both devices have sufficient power.

Comment: Did you add Arduino library into Python?

Comment: What happens on the arduino side?  Are you getting the Pi transmission?  How do you have the two devices wired?  Do you have sufficient current on the interface lines to get a valid high & low signal?  Suggest you provide more details, if you expect us to answer.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have edited my post, hopefully this helps in explaining it a bit better.